# Random white pixels on screen

Tags: ati, graphics, display, radeon

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 installed with a ATI Radeon HD 6550D. The problem is, that sometimes, there are random white pixels at the screen, which appears especially on dark areas of the screen. This is really annoying during work, and even more when watching movies (XBMC frodo is installed on that machine, but the pixels also appears on the desktop).

I thought, maybe it's sth with the graphic card driver. So I tried some ATI drivers and some other (weird) stuff, but the problem still exists.

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

### AND

[image]

Hope, somebody can help me. thx!

Comment: Nobody an idea? Are there known issues with some drivers that will cause such problems?

Comment: I have a similar issue with a Radeon R7 240, just with green flickering pixels. The issue seems to go away if I set the screen to a lower resolution and then bring it back to the previous one. Can you try this and let me know if it helps?

Comment: Aside, Try a different cable. this could just as well be a bad wire or connection between the wire and the connector.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue.  Ubuntu 12.04 hdmi A8 APU and same HD 6550D GPU  The weird thing is it only happens when I am doing full 1080P out over hdmi.  My new tv also had trouble detecting anything being displayed.  Had ubuntu running fine on an old 720P samsung lcd, now with a new 1080P samsung it is throwing a fit.  I installed 3 different catalyst drivers and followed a guide in the ubuntu forums and say that any switchable graphics is really not supported??  Also getting red dots only in xbmc during dark scenes.

Answer (score 0):

I has a similar issue in some GPUs where where was excessive heating, and in others where the GPU filter capacitors were failing.  You might investigate cleaning your heat-sink, and looking for signs of venting capacitors. You might also look into better cooling options. You can investigate heat using `sensors` from the lm-sensors package.

Your screen could also be having performance issues, such as stuck pixels.(Pixels that are slow to respond, or stuck in a given colour)